# Android Java "error: cannot find symbol variable action_refresh"

Tags: java, android

When I am looking at my code there are no errors but when I hit build as apk it shows the following error "cannot find symbol variable action_refresh" here is the code:

ForecastFragment.java

```
package com.alexander.sunshine;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Encapsulates fetching the forecast and displaying it as a {@link ListView} layout.
 */
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
            weatherTask.execute("Belfast");
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Create some dummy data for the ListView.  Here's a sample weekly forecast
        String[] data = {
                "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
                "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
                "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
                "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
                "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
                "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
                "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
        };
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));

        // Now that we have some dummy forecast data, create an ArrayAdapter.
        // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source (like our dummy forecast) and
        // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
        ArrayAdapter<String> forecastAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                        R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                        weekForecast);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(forecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

        private String getReadableDateString(long time) {
            SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM ddd");
            return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
        }

        private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
            long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
            long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

            String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
            return highLowStr;
        }

        private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays) throws JSONException {
            final String OWM_LIST = "list";
            final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
            final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
            final String OWM_MAX = "max";
            final String OWM_MIN = "min";
            final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

            JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

            Time dayTime = new Time();
            dayTime.setToNow();

            int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

            dayTime = new Time();

            String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
            for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
                String day;
                String description;
                String highAndLow;

                JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

                long dateTime;

                dateTime =  dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
                day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

                JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

                JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

                highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
                resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
            }
            return resultStrs;
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.

            if (params.length == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            String format = "json";
            String units = "metric";
            int numDays = 7;

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                final String FORECAST_BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
                final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
                final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
                final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";

                Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                        .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                        .build();

                URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            if (result != null) {
                mForecastAdapter.clear();
                for (String dayForecastStr : result) {
                    mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

forecastfragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:andorid="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item andorid:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just a typo: `andorid` for `android`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Comment: I'm now getting the error "Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute" and when I click on jump to source it takes me to line 2 on forecastfragment.xml, it also says on line 5 that "Menu items should specify a title"

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that. It was the `tools` that was bad. Now it should work ;)

Answer (score 0):

look here

```
xmlns:andorid="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item andorid:id="@+id/action_refresh"
```

change andorid to android

Comment: isnt this the same as the other answer posted 10 minutes ago?

Comment: I'm now getting the error "Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute" and when I click on jump to source it takes me to line 2 on forecastfragment.xml

Comment: Just clean and build your project and then check.